# I want to prove $P$ is true (by contradiction). What happens if I deduce $Q$ from $\lnot P$, knowing $\lnot Q$, then replace $Q$ with $P$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have a quick question about reasoning by contradiction.

Suppose I want to prove that a proposition $P$ is true (by contradiction).
I will suppose that $\neg P$ is true and I will try to deduce that a proposition $Q$ is true, knowing that $\neg Q$ is true.
I will conclude by saying that $P$ is true.

My question is the following: is this point of view works if I replace $Q$ by $P$ ?

If yes, it seems a bit strange to me... do you have an example where we can do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, assume $\lnot P$ and conclude $P$ that is a contradiction.  But in general you *won't* be about to conclude $P$ from  $\lnot P$ unless you are able to conclude $P$ from the get go, in which case you might as well do a direct proof... for example the following *is* valid (but weird). Pf: 17+63 is even. Pf: Assume 17+63 is odd.  Well 17+63=80 which is even. That's a contradiction. So we had 17+63 is even after all.

Comment: "unless you are able to conclude P from the get go": only on that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you *could*....

Okay, you actually bring up a subtle point.

When you assume $\lnot P$ and conclude $Q$ that you know is false, it doesn't *have* to be that you know $Q$ is false.  It's that you know $Q$ together with $\lnot P$ can't be true.

Let's suppose... bear with me.... this is purely hypothetical.

You need to prove $n$ is even.  And somehow there is a number $w =  n-7$. (Since it will turn out that $n$ is even it will turn out that $w$ is odd... but we don't *KNOW* either of those yet.  We have no idea if $n$ or $w$ are even or odd.)

You assume that $n$ is odd.  And somehow you manage to prove, god knows how, that if $n$ is odd then $w$ is odd.  But that means $n-7$ is odd but if $n$ is odd then $n-7$ is even.  That's a contradiction.  SO $n$ is even.

But note $w$ being odd *isn't* a contradiction!  In fact as it turns out $w$ *was* odd!  The contradiction wasn't "$w$ is odd".  The contradiction was "$n$ is odd and $w=n-7$ is also odd".

.....

So assuming $\lnot P$ and reaching the conclusion $P$......

Well, you don't know that $P$ is false (and if you actually did this it would mean $P$ is true!) so concluding $P$ is *not* the contradiction.

But concluding $P$ is true *WHILE* assuming $P$ is also false, is the contradiction.

So.... $P$ must be true.

That is a valid proof by contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

An interpretation of your question is equivalent to asking whether $$((\lnot P)\to P)\to P\tag{$\Sigma$}$$ is a tautology.

Indeed, suppose otherwise; that is, $$\lnot (((\lnot P)\to P)\to P)\tag{1}$$ is true. Then we have both $$(\lnot P)\to P\tag{2}$$ and $$\lnot P\tag{3}$$ from $(1)$. Then $(2)$ gives either: $$\lnot\lnot P,\tag{4$i$}$$ *i.e.*, $$P,\tag{5}$$ and so $(5)$ contradicts $(3)$; or, $$P,\tag{4$ii$}$$ which also contradicts $(3)$.

Hence $(\Sigma)$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

It actually happens all the time, especially when $P$ is naturally expressed as the negation of something.

Here's a less weird example than fleablood's.
Let $P$ be "$3 \cdot k \ne 4$", where $k$ is a natural number (in other words, we're proving $4$ is not divisible by $3$). Here's a proof:

Assume $\neg P$, i.e.  $3 \cdot k = 4$.  There are two cases to consider:

1. if $k \le 1$, then $3 \cdot k \le 3 \cdot 1 = 3$, and $3 < 4$, so $3 \cdot k \ne 4$ (i.e. $P$).
2. if $k \ge 2$, then $3 \cdot k \ge 3 \cdot 2 = 6$, and $6 > 4$, so $3 \cdot k \ne 4$ (i.e. $P$ again).

Thus, assuming $\neg P$, we deduce $P$.  We conclude $P$ is true.